# CI/CD ArgoCD - how can we schedule a nightly build with ArgoCD? So deploy a temporary set of Kubernetes resources

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, argocd

Each night we run a nightly build. A 'docker-compose' stack is deployed, a Test docker container runs the tests. Works fine.

We started migrating to Kubernetes with ArgoCD.

How can we deploy a temporary set of Kubernetes resources with ArgoCD? So on any change in a Git config file, ArgoCD will update a series of e.g. 20 Kubernetes resources in a running environment.

Try 1: In [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73490564/3143823) is suggested to set the number of instances for deployable resources to 0. OK, that works fine for a limited set of resources.

Try 2: We can create dynamically an ArgoCD application so it will immediately start creating the set of Kubernetes resources in the runtime environment. After some time this ArgoCD application should be deleted. Possible, but is this a good way to go? Is this how companies run their nightly builds? There should be a better way.

Try 3: Can we work with pull requests? With tagging items?

I hope you can suggest a better solution!